# Minimum polynomial intermediate field cyclotomic extension

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to find the minimum polynomial of the generators of the subfields of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{13})$. We have:
$$G:=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{13})/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$$
In particular, I am dealing with $H_6=<12>=\{1,12\}$, which has index 6 in $G$ and order 2. By the Galois correspondence, it corresponds to the intermediate field of index 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$, $K_6=\mathbb{Q}(\eta_6)$. Explicitly, $\eta_6=\xi+ \xi^{12}$. Its five other conjugates are:
$$\sigma_2(\eta_6)=\xi^2+\xi^{11}$$
$$\sigma_3(\eta_6)=\xi^3+\xi^{10}$$
$$\sigma_4(\eta_6)=\xi^4+\xi^{9}$$
$$\sigma_5(\eta_6)=\xi^5+\xi^{8}$$
$$\sigma_7(\eta_6)=\xi^6+\xi^{7}$$
Therefore:
$$f^{\eta_6}_{\mathbb{Q}}=(X-\eta_6)(X-\sigma_2(\eta_6))(X-\sigma_3(\eta_6))(X-\sigma_4(\eta_6))(X-\sigma_5(\eta_6))(X-\sigma_7(\eta_6))$$
$$=X^6+aX^5+bX^4+cX^3+dX^2+eX+f$$
I managed to get $a=1,b=-5,f=-1$ by hand (multiplying all the polynomials and equating powers of X), but the rest are too tedious to compute by hand and I was wondering if there was any other way I could get them to obtain $f^{\eta_6}_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, yes, there is a classic trick somewhat-easing such computations: from the $13$ cyclotomic polynomial $x^{12}+x^{11}+\ldots+x+1=0$, divide through by $x^6$, to obtain $x^6+x^5+\ldots+x+1+x^{-1}+\ldots+x^{-6}=0$. Then iteratively express the left-hand side in powers of $y=x+x^{-1}$, starting with $y^6=x^6+6x^4+15x^2+20+15x^{-2}+6x^{-4}+x^{-6}$. Subtracting this from the left-hand-side leaves a lower-degree polynomial,
$$
x^5-5x^4+x^3-14x^2+x-19 + x^{-1}-14x^{-2}+x^{-3}-5x^{-4}+x^{-5}
$$
From the extreme terms $x^5$ and $x^{-5}$, we see that we should subtract $y^5=x^5+5x^3+\ldots+x^{-5}$, leaving
$$
-5x^4-4x^3-14x^2-9x-19-9x^{-1}-14x^{-2}-4x^{-3}-5x^{-4}
$$
From the extreme terms, $-5x^4$ and $=5x^{-4}$, we see that we should add $5y^4$, ... and continue.

Comment: It absolutely worked, of course! One little thing: Second to last line should say $...-9x^{-1}$.

Comment: @cut, oops, thanks for noticing, I'll repair it... :)